# 2005 toyota tundra double cab special edition - rear axle seal replacement

Tags: toyota, seal, tundra

Is this vehicle safe to drive if needing a rear axle seal replaced? It is leaking and unsure what oil needs to go back in her ... appointment booked for next week, but wondering if its safe for use until then?

Answer (score 1):

Your truck should be fine to drive as long as you take the following precautions. The main thing is you ensure you keep the gear oil topped off to where it should be. Gear oil doesn't leak like out like engine oil. You should only need to top it off once or twice to maintain the gear oil level (unless it's *really* leaking --- I'm assuming it isn't gushing out, lol). The only other precaution to take is making sure the gear oil isn't getting on your brakes, which is a possibility. If it looks like it's getting onto your brakes, you'll want to stop driving it as a safety precaution.

**NOTE:** Images and directions were obtained from [this website](http://www.tundrasolutions.com/forums/engine-intake-exhaust-induction/125266-diy-differential-oil-drain-and-fill/). Full instructions for replacing the gear oil can be found there.

I believe your truck requires 75w85 gear oil, but 75w90 should work just fine for the mean time. You can get the gear oil at pretty much any parts store or Walmart.

To check your fluid, there should be a 24mm plug in the rear differential which will be below centerline (half way point of the differential) on the back cover:

[image]

You'll want to use this hole to fill this up the gear oil level until you have less than 5mm of space between the drain hole and the top of the gear oil. If you use the tip of your little finger (to the first joint) and can feel the gear oil through the hole, you should be in good shape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Axles don't hold much oil and if you don't know how much is left in I wouldn't risk it without topping it up